# "RPC server unavailable" error using WMI win32_computersystem in Powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi, rpc

I've read through other RPC posts and haven't found my situation.

I'm using remote desktop onto our PDC server as administrator and running powershell scripts to retrieve info about computers on our network.  I type in the following command into powershell:

```
get-wmiobject win32_computersystem -computer "PC1"
```

PC1 is my computer that i'm using to remote onto the server.  This works fine.

When I replace the computer name with another, identically setup, computer name that is on my network I get the error:

"The RPC server is unavailable."

So i'm guessing that the remote session is allowing the request to work or maybe i need to impersonate the user who's computer I'm trying to access.

I've checked the RPC and WMI services are running on server and client computer.  the firewall is turned off on the client computer.

On the server, in Powershell I am running as the administrator.

Any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: "*the firewall is turned off on the client computer.*" - by 'client computer', you mean the remote workstation running the RPC server, or the server you're on by RDP which is the client making an RPC connection?

Comment: Sorry, the remote workstation that I am trying to access has it's firewall turned off.  The server that i'm running this powershell script from does have firewall enabled. but the script works when accessing the workstation I am remoting onto the server from.

Comment: OK; Can you ping it by hostname? Is it on another subnet? You say it's "identically setup", but if that's the case then it leaves very little reason why it doesn't work - you don't need to impersonate the user who regularly uses a computer, as long as your credentials are an admin on that computer. Sure it doesn't have antivirus with firewall enabled? Can you map a drive to it - `New-PSDrive -Name 'test' -PSProvider FileSystem -root '\\computer\c$' -Credential (get-credential)` ?

Comment: Test-Connection "PC2" works and returns a few records with the correct IP address.  Not sure about setting up drive. what is the get-credential part of your code? Should i use the -credential option on my original expression?

Comment: also it is not on another subnet.

Comment: Solved.  I signed into my local computer as the domain administrator. Then when I remote desktop onto the server (as the admin as always) and ran my scripts they worked great.  No Idea on what is going on with the authentication here but wanted to share my fix.  Thanks for the input.